# Cant console log array data (which was pushed from promise)

Tags: javascript, promise

So basically this is the code to get users' location, after fetching the data from Promise I can't use it outside, I tried using push array object but can't use its value.

```js
let addr = [];
var lati;
var long;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  lati = position.coords.latitude;
  long = position.coords.longitude;
  revgeo();
}

function revgeo(){
  const KEY = "api";
  const LAT = lati;
  const LNG = long;
  let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${LAT},${LNG}&key=${KEY}`;

  fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          addr.push(data.results[0].formatted_address);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err.message));
}


window.onload = getLocation();

console.log(addr); // this works
console.log(addr[0]); // this doesn't work
```

Comment: What is the result when you console log addr?

Comment: Also see [is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) for the logging behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call the google API (ie your `fetch` operation) it will take a few milliseconds to complete. Your code below (outside of your `fetch` callback) executes *before* the fetch call has finished. Here is an example of what is happening.

```js
let todo = null;
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    todo = json;
    console.log('First Log', todo);
  })
  
  console.log('Second Log', todo);
```

Notice how the `Second Log` takes place before the `First Log`.

To fix this, you can simply move your logic so it takes place in your callback and therefore doesn't execute until the `fetch` call has finished. The other option is to use `async/await`

```js
const getTodo = async (id) => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch( e => reject(e) );

const init = async () => {
  const todo = await getTodo(1);
  console.log(todo);
};

init();
```

Comment: `fetch(...)` already returns a promise, so no need to use the promise constructor to wrap the `fetch()` call. See: [unnecessary use of promise constructor](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/common-promise-anti-patterns#unnecessary-use-of-promise-constructor)

Comment: I always forget that.

Comment: Edited code will not work; you forgot to remove the `reject` function call in the callback function of the `catch` method. I suggest you remove the `catch` method call from the `getTodo` function and allow the `init` method to handle the error by adding the `try-catch` block around `await getTodo(1);`

Comment: It works fine. This is just an example for the OP to understand the basic issue. Feel free to provide your own answer.